# Wol.service not starting successfully

Tags: 22.04, wakeonlan

I spent hours trying to get my Ubuntu 22.04 works in the WOL configuration. I've done the following:

- Ensuring every reboot the ethtool will show the enp7s0 interface flagged as "g"
- create a wol.service (but this service will not start, with the error message as follow)

```
wol.service - Enable Wake-On Lan
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wol.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2023-12-02 16:18:06 UTC; 30min ago
   Main PID: 2068 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms

Dec 02 16:18:06 systemd[1]: Starting Enable Wake On Lan...

Dec 02 16:18:06 systemd[1]: wol.service: Deactivated successfully.

Dec 02 16:18:06 systemd[1]: Finished Enable Wake On Lan.
```

Although by now every reboot the eth interface flagged with "g", but i tried sending magic packet after a suspend, the machine just won't boot back up, so likely relates to the wol.service not being active, is there anything I've to do to ensure the wol.service started successfully?

The wol.service configuration is as follow:

```
[Unit]
Description=Enable Wake-On Lan

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart = /sbin/ethtool --change enp7s0 wol g

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Appreciate some guidance in this, many thanks

Comment: Have you [Enabled WoL in the BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan#Enabling_WoL_in_the_BIOS)? ... Your systemd service seems to be doing its job as you describe (although I would tie it to e.g. [`After=network.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/)).

Comment: Yea BIOS enabled, I too tried the "After=network.target" but it didn't solve the issue of wol.service not starting up

Comment: OK ... There shouldn't be spaces around `=` in the service unit file ... i.e. `ExecStart = /sbin/ethtool ...` should be `ExecStart=/sbin/ethtool ...`

Comment: I will double check that and made necessary correction in next hour, away from my PC now :-)

Comment: I've removed the space for the ExecStart command, save and issues a systemctl daemon-reload command and enable the service. Still the same issue, the service just start and deactivated rightaway

Comment: That's normal as it's defined as `oneshot` and your command is run successfully but it doesn't take long time to execute ... It is still run however ... You shouldn't expect more from that service or that command except setting the `g` flag on the interface which you report is successful ... Focus away from those two as to what might be the culprit ... IMO

Comment: arh, makes sense, which means the service is started and did what it supposed to do (by flagging the g to the wakeonlan capability of the eth interface), so does that mean that after a successful execute it'll just stop the service by its own?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what SUCCESS in `(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)` and then  `inactive (dead)` means AFAIK

Comment: thanks, I'll relook into other area and see how else i can send a magic packet to wake up the computer, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems I nailed the issue, it was the memory configuration in the BIOS for the AMD system. Issue to wake-on-lan when memory are set at EXPO configuration, once i reverted to Auto (not as performant), the wake-on-LAN works expectedly.

I'll get the BIOS updated to the latest version and try for wake-on-LAN with EXPO memory configuration.

Thanks